# error: 'sort' is not a member of 'std::ranges'; did you mean 'std::sort'?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, g++10

I ran the following code

```
vector<int> randomIntegers = generateIntegers(10); // Generates 10 integers

std::ranges::sort(randomIntegers);
```

When I compile with `g++ -std=c++20 file.cpp` , I get

```
error: 'sort' is not a member of 'std::ranges'; did you mean 'std::sort'?
```

- `gcc --version`: gcc 10.2.0
- `g++ --version`: g++ 10.2.0

Why is sort not a member? I'm using VScode intellisense, and it shows methods such as `advance`,`begin`,`common_view`. But not sort.

Comment: Did you `#include <algorithm>`?

Comment: Pro tip: Always check [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sort) - it'll tell you right at the top what header you need.  It isn't always obvious.  (E.g., why is `std::accumulate` not in `<algorithm>`?  Dunno, [but it's not ...](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get access to [`std::ranges::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sort) you need to `#include <algorithm>`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> randomIntegers{9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0}; // some integers

    std::ranges::sort(randomIntegers);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/63EW7h)

Answer (score 1):

[ranges api](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges)

However you can use sort as follows:

```
#include <algorithm>
std::sort(randomIntegers.begin(), randomIntegers.end());
```